# How can I put Powershell pipeline output into a command that doesn't support pipeline input (multiple arguments)?

Tags: powershell, pipe, command-line-interface, pipeline

I'm trying to use Powershell to take a list of outdated chocolatey packages and stuff them into the `choco upgrade` command, which takes a space-separated list: `choco upgrade <pkg> [<pkg2 <pkgN>]`.

This much works as expected to get and format the list:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (choco outdated -r | %{$_.split('|')[0]}) -join ' '
google-drive-file-stream intel-dsa malwarebytes paint.net powertoys zoom
```

Just adding a  `| choco upgrade` is out of the question because it doesn't accept pipeline input. So I want to insert the result of the pipeline as if it were arguments to the command, as if I'd just typed this:
`choco upgrade google-drive-file-stream intel-dsa malwarebytes paint.net powertoys zoom`

These were my best guesses:
`(choco outdated -r | %{$_.split('|')[0]}) -join ' ' | %{choco upgrade $_}`
`choco upgrade ((choco outdated -r | %{$_.split('|')[0]}) -join ' ')`
but it seems that they're inserting the whole list as one argument, including the spaces:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> choco upgrade ((choco outdated -r | %{$_.split('|')[0]} | Select-Object -skiplast 1) -join ' ')
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Upgrading the following packages:
google-drive-file-stream intel-dsa malwarebytes paint.net powertoys
By upgrading you accept licenses for the packages.
google-drive-file-stream intel-dsa malwarebytes paint.net powertoys is not installed. Installing...
google-drive-file-stream intel-dsa malwarebytes paint.net powertoys not installed. The package was not found with the source(s) listed.
```

How can I insert all of these values as if they're separate arguments?

(I'm aiming for a one-liner. I'm interested in a PS-idiomatic way to do it, but any hack that works, works.)

Comment: Also, I'm not looking for `| %{choco upgrade $_}`, which runs the command once for each input. I want to run it once with multiple inputs, because it may handle that differently.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `(choco outdated -r | %{$_.split('|')[0]}) -join ' ')` is taken as only one parameter.

Try to avoid the problem with invoke-Expression :

```
iex "choco upgrade $((choco outdated -r | %{$_.split('|')[0]}) -join ' ')"
```

Note : I have successfuly used this command on my  computer:

```
iex "choco upgrade $((choco outdated -r | %{ ($_ -split "\.install|\|")[0] }) -join " ") -y"
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing the arguments as an array works:

```
$myargs = '/i','hi'
echo Hi | findstr $myargs

Hi
```

So, keeping the first output as an array:

```
choco upgrade (choco outdated -r | %{$_.split('|')[0]})
```

Or

```
choco upgrade ((choco outdated -r) -replace '\|.*')
```